# QT how to connect to SQLite database

Tags: qt

I am trying to connect to a database I created using DB BROWSER for SQLite have used this code to connect to my database. But it keeps giving errors while compiling. I tried following a YouTube tutorial as well and did as it said but got loads of errors.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(":/accounts/login.db");
db.open();
```

the errors I am getting:

```
agent.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl QSqlDatabase::setDatabaseName(class QString const &)" (__imp_?setDatabaseName@QSqlDatabase@@QEAAXAEBVQString@@@Z)
<br>referenced in function<br>
"public: __cdecl agent::agent(class QWidget *)" (??0agent@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
```

```
agent.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "_declspec(dllimport) public: static char const * const QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection" (__imp?defaultConnection@QSqlDatabase@@2PEBDEB) 
<br>referenced in function<br>
"public: __cdecl agent::agent(class QWidget *)" (??0agent@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
```

```
agent.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "_declspec(dllimport) public: static class QSqlDatabase __cdecl QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(class QString const &,class QString const &)" (__imp?addDatabase@QSqlDatabase@@SA?AV1@AEBVQString@@0@Z)
<br>referenced in function<br>
"public: __cdecl agent::agent(class QWidget *)" (??0agent@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
```

```
agent.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "_declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl QSqlDatabase::setDatabaseName(class QString const &)" (__imp?setDatabaseName@QSqlDatabase@@QEAAXAEBVQString@@@Z)
<br>referenced in function<br>
"public: __cdecl agent::agent(class QWidget *)" (??0agent@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
```

```
agent.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class QSqlDatabase __cdecl QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(class QString const &,class QString const &)" (__imp_?addDatabase@QSqlDatabase@@SA?AV1@AEBVQString@@0@Z)
<br>referenced in function<br>
"public: __cdecl agent::agent(class QWidget *)" (??0agent@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
```

```
agent.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static char const * const QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection" (__imp_?defaultConnection@QSqlDatabase@@2PEBDEB)
<br>referenced in function<br>
"public: __cdecl agent::agent(class QWidget *)" (??0agent@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
```

Comment: I expect your bug is in your `.pro` file. The documentation states the need for: `QT += sql` [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html)

Comment: I dont understand what i need to do

Comment: Add `QT += sql` to your .pro file after the other `QT +=` lines assuming that you are using Qt-Creator and/or QMake.

Comment: This may help you understand Qt modules: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmodules.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmodules.html)